For every folder, if parent folder contains subfolder of the same name, move everything to respective parent folder
So you have a command like this:
for %F in (c:\foo\bar\*.*) do move /Y %F c:\foo

But this requires knowing the name of the parent folder you wish to fix.
What if you have to fix 1000 parent folders?  Then that code is impractical.
new -> new -> resources + files
should become:
new -> resources + files
folder2 -> folder2 -> resources + files
should become:
folder2 -> resources + files
..
998 more parent folders to fix.
Every subfolder must simply be integrated into its respective parent.
What is not desired is having all the files and folders from all directories in one directory; I can do that with my eyes closed.
All I know is I'm sure the solution requires tokens, but how to use this correctly to mass fix 1000 parent folders of any name with the same name subfolder requires special hands.

PowerShell should be able to easily do this, other than the fact you don't have a single line of code for us to review; making it a command prompt script makes doing this unnecessarily complicated.

powershell solutions will be accepted and appreciated

Welcome to this site. Just a suggestion, but perhaps start with "I'm trying to do X", then continue with "I tried Y script, but it didn't work because Z", and end with  "How can I accomplish X?" The Title of the post should be like the title of a book: short and interesting. Right now yours is the only place you actually tell us what you want to do.

It is conceptually not easy to explain much less to title correctly without overlap of similar easier problems, but thanks.

Should it also move subfolders or just the files?

Would this be as expected: https://i.imgur.com/x0r16kr.gif

Let's simplify to your alfa in the gif.  So it's alfa within alfa, and in that alfa subfolder you have a resource folder + other files; basically move the second alfa and all its content to the first alpha, but  this needs to be doable in bulk...repeat the pattern with beta and so on...so the gif is not as expected, subfolders should be copied too, so the primary alpha has the resource folder + files once the batch runs...the primary beta has the resource folder + files once the batch runs

so what happened is I chose extract to separate folders a bunch of archives, and it sucker punched by putting everything in a subfolder of the name of the parent folder; and I was cursing mad fury because it mixed in with hundreds of other folders that were already there; I'm temped to email rarlabs and tell them to put an option to make sure that doesn't happen.

"basically move the second alfa and all its content to the first alpha" this doesn't make sense to me since the second alpha is already inside the first alpha and that would let everything as is...I got that only the contents including subfolder of alpha2 should be moved to alpha1 ?? https://i.imgur.com/zqWqfk2.gif

If it is "conceptually not easy to explain", then just do your best. There are lots of complex and difficult to explain questions on this site that have been communicated well enough to be understood. That is on you to do this with your question.

Well if it is like I understood it, it would be something like this inside a batch script:
:: Set the basefolder here
set BaseFolder=Test

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%BaseFolder%"') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /b "%BaseFolder%\%%a"') do if "%%a"=="%%b" for /f "delims=" %%c in ('dir /b "%BaseFolder%\%%a\%%b"') do move "%BaseFolder%\%%a\%%b\%%c" "%BaseFolder%\%%a\"
pause

Where %%a would be the first level subfolder, %%b would be the second level subfolder and %%c would be the files and subfolders to be moved in case %%a and %%b have the same name.
This would be the command line to be used outside of a batch script assuming Test as the base folder:
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /ad "Test"') do for /f "delims=" %b in ('dir /b "Test\%a"') do if "%a"=="%b" for /f "delims=" %c in ('dir /b "Test\%a\%b"') do move "Test\%a\%b\%c" "Test\%a\"

